# .dropDestination doesn't execute with my custom transferable type

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, drag-and-drop, draggable

I have defined

```swift
import SwiftUI
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

enum LayerType: String, Codable, RawRepresentable {
    case text
    case image
}

struct TransferableLayer: Identifiable, Hashable, Codable, Transferable {
    var id: UUID
    var type: LayerType
    
    init(id: UUID, type: LayerType) {
        self.id = id
        self.type = type
    }

    static var transferRepresentation: some TransferRepresentation {
        CodableRepresentation(contentType: .transferableLayer)
    }
}

extension UTType {
    static let transferableLayer = UTType(exportedAs: "co.customUTType.transferableLayer")
}
```

**Note:** I've added it in Exported Type Identifiers as well:
[image]

Also I have `LayersView` where I assign .draggable attribute to Text:

```
 ForEach(Array(textLayers.enumerated()), id: \.element.id) { index, textLayer in
                    ...
                        Text(textLayer.text)
                           .draggable(TransferableLayer(id: textLayer.id, type: LayerType.text))
...
}
```

and I have PanelView where I added

```
.dropDestination(for: TransferableLayer.self) { droppedLayers, location in
   print("I'm inside dropDestination")
}
```

and `print()` code inside dropDestination doesn't call when I drag'n'drop my textLayer on Panel. But it shows preview properly and I see changes which I've made there.

**UPD:**

I've searched for similar question/answers on SO and found this one:
[Drag&Drop Custom Types with Transferable Protocol in Swiftui for macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76977111/dragdrop-custom-types-with-transferable-protocol-in-swiftui-for-macos)

Seems issue to Transferable protocol and how it works with Custom types on MacOS. BTW it works on Supported Destination as Mac Catalyst

Comment: What's the purpose of `.position(textLayer.position)`? Does it work if you remove that?

Comment: @Sweeper I've updated my question. Actually `.position(textLayer.position)` is not related to this question. It doesn't work if I remove it as well.

Answer (score 1):

CodableRepresentation is JSON, which is text.

You are using an Exported Type Identifier that conforms to com.public.data.

Use public.text instead.